# Canvas in foreign object of svg doesn't apply the transformation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, transformation

I have a problem with the use of a canvas in svg, using foreignObject.

The probleme is that the canvas is inserted in a group, which have a transformation (translation or rotation or scale), but the canvas isn't printed with the transformation.

I am on Chrome.

You can see my example there :

https://jsfiddle.net/Surre/qjrvxgos/

```
<body>
  <svg width="400px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 400 300"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org2000/svg">
       <g transform='translate(250,10)rotate(40)'>
         <foreignObject height="700" width="370" y="0" x="0">
             <span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
             <canvas id="canvas" width="400px" height="300px" fill-style="#FF0000"></canvas>
             <div>Comment</div>
             </span>
         </foreignObject>
       </g>
  </svg>
</body>
```

The "Comment" has the good transformation, but the canvas hasn't.
But if you use dev tools and inspect element canvas, you will see that it's like he is in the good place, with the transformation.

Hoping you can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for that, I corrected it

Comment: Presumably a Chrome bug, why not report it to their bugtracker?

Comment: Question: why are you using a canvas element in your SVG at all? This looks like SVG as used in an HTML5 page, so a few things should be done here: 1) svg is part of HTML5, officially, so no XML namespaces. 2) same for all those other elements: no namespaces. 3) why not just put the canvas on the page itself instead of inside the SVG? What are you concretely trying to do here, because this is just a webpage, and it looks like you're using SVG to do things CSS can already do.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans only the SVGRoot node is in html namespace, all its children are in svg one. elements contained in a foreignObject that don't belong to the svg namespace need to have their own namespace declared, at the very least on all first parents nodes. But the svg root's xmlns declaration has a typo, could this cause the wrong behavior from chrome? I would be suprised about it, but if set, OP should set it correctly.

Comment: no, you miss the point. SVG **is** HTML5, there are no "namespaces" in HTML5, the `<svg>` element is a first class citizen like `<p>` or `<div>` and does *not* need namespacing, you just use it like any other HTML element. That also means you don't "escape" SVG namespacing for things like `<span>`. It's *all* just HTML elements.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans only the HTMLSVG root node. All other elements inside the HTMLSVG element belong to the SVG namespace. try it yourself... And when you use an foreignObject, with elements that belong to an other namespace than the svg one (why use fO otherwise ?), you have to declare this other namespace. And to maybe more convince yourself, you can simply search for an HTMLRect or HTMLCircle element in any specs, you won't dind them, while there is both SVGSvg element and HTMLSvg element.

Comment: I use svg because my foreign object (canvas) is a member of a group of objects that have to apply somes svg's transformations, it's why I prefer to avoid using css only for the canvas. All my object must follow the move (svg's transformation).

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, this is actually a bug in chrome that's been known about since 2015 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=467484 There's talk of fixing it

I needed a solution too though, so here's what I've put together; I use the image element (which functions fine in svg) in conjunction with a hidden canvas. The system draws all it likes to the canvas, then transfers the canvas data to the image element.

```
imageElement.setAttribute('href',hiddenCanvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
```

It's an extra step, but it produces essentially the same result. In my project I've bundled this all together into an JS element maker

```
this.canvas = function(id=null, x=0, y=0, width=0, height=0, angle=0, res=1){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.setAttribute('height',res*height);
        canvas.setAttribute('width',res*width);

    var image = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
        image.id = id;
        image.style = 'transform: translate('+x+'px,'+y+'px) scale('+1/res+') rotate('+angle+'rad)';
        image.setAttribute('height',height*res);
        image.setAttribute('width',width*res);

    return {
        element:image,
        canvas:canvas,
        context:canvas.getContext("2d"),
        c:function(a){return a*res;},
        print:function(){
            this.element.setAttribute('href',this.canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
        }
    };
};
```

It's kinda clunky, but I think it's what you need. It also handles resolution with the 'res' argument, and the 'c' function (which you can use with any of the canvas drawing functions

```
canvas.context.fillRect(canvas.c(0), canvas.c(0), canvas.c(width), canvas.c(height));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you neither rotate nor transform your canvas. If you want to rotate/transform it you can use CSS style. See the below code.

```
.transform {
    -ms-transform:translateX(200px) rotate(40deg) translateY(130px); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:translateX(200px) rotate(40deg) translateY(130px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform:translateX(200px) rotate(40deg) translateY(130px);
    background:#FF0000;
}
```

This css code will work on most of the browsers. You can use this class in your example like the following.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400px" height="300px"  class="transform"></canvas>
```

You can see on https://jsfiddle.net/qjrvxgos/3/ your example with my update.

Comment: I put the canvas in the group which have a transformation and want it to follow, like other objects in the group. When you open the dev tools, and inspect the canvas element, you can see that the canvas isn't where the tools show you. The tools show that it is translated ans rotated like it should be.

Comment: It's a member of a group of objects that have to apply somes transformations, it's why I prefer to avoid using css for only it.

Answer (score -2):

Canvas and SVG are different libraries, you can't use them together. You can convert one to another to do what you need. see the following link may it helps you http://www.inkfood.com/svg-to-canvas/ also you can do your example like the following example

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g transform='translate(250,10)rotate(40)'>
 <rect x="10" y="20" height="50" width="75"
      style="stroke: #ffff00; fill: #ff0000"/>
    <text x="10" y="90" style="stroke: #660000; fill: #ff0000">
    Comment</text>
</g>
```

Comment: Thank for the link, it could help, maybe.
But in normal case we can use a canvas in svg with a foreign object. But how to deal with this bug I mentioned ?